# Why objection instance method did not work

Tags: node.js, database, express, objection.js

I have setup the Objection model for Company, if I use static method to query database it is OK. (I already have Model.knex(knex) before to setup everything.)

```
const companyInfo = await Company.query().findById(1)
```

But if I create company instance and then use instance method, get error - one of the identifier columns [id] is null or undefined. Even I add idColumn in model still got this error, seems not really relevant.

```
const company = new Company()
const companyInfo = await company.$query().findById(1)
```

Why I need use this way because I want to use Dependency Injection to inject model instance into my service. Does anyone know why this instance based way does not work?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem? I've the same issue.